# Regular expression which match with empty/blank message

Tags: regex

I am working on a regular expression, which match with empty message or blank message.

I need to know if someone send to us a "blank" message with only spaces or tabulations or new lines for examples.

Here what i have done, but i'm not happy with this:

```
^[\n,\r]{2,}$
```

Thanks

Comment: Just `trim` the string and see if it's empty.

Comment: Why `{2,}` not `*` (meaning `{0,}`)? A blank message doesn't need any newlines.  Also, use `\s` instead of `\r\n` for any whitespace.

Comment: To sum up @Sam suggestion, you could use `^\s*$` instead.

Comment: @sp00m What sp00m said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm explaining first the regular expression `^[\n,\r]{2,}$` in the question.

`^` ... start the search at beginning of the message string.

`[\n,\r]` ... a character class definition matching either a line-feed `\n` (newline) or a comma `,` or a carriage return `\r`. Comma is not really wanted here. The questioner most likely thought that the characters in the expression need to be comma separated, but this is not true.

`{2,}` ... means the character class definition - the OR of the 3 characters - should be applied at least 2 times or more times for a positive result.

`$` ... stop the search at end of the message string.

So the expression `^[\n,\r]{2,}$` returns positive if the entire message string consists of at least 2 characters which are either a comma, or a carriage return, or a line-feed. If the message string is empty (no characters), or has only 1 of those 3 characters, or contains any other character, the expression returns negative which means string not found. Therefore the regular expression of the questioner is not useful to validate if a message is a blank or empty message.

---

Sam and sp00 wrote in their comments to use instead `^\s*$` which is much better as this expression means.

`^` ... start the search at beginning of the message string.

`\s` ... match any whitespace charater. See [Perl regular expression character class description](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) for details what is matched by `\s` when using Perl v5.18. It should be tested which of the whitespace characters is really matched by the used regular expression engine by `\s`. Especially the no-break space character is interesting here also for a check against blank / empty message.

`*` ... means the character class definition - any whitespace character - should be applied at least 0 times or more times for a positive result.

`$` ... stop the search at end of the message string.

So the expression `^\s*$` returns positive if the entire message string has no characters at all or consists only of 1 or more whitespace characters. That expression is therefore much better to check against a blank / empty message.

---

Another useful and simple regular expression is `^\W*$` which returns positive if the entire message has no characters at all or has only non word characters.

A message without any letter or digit or underscore is most likely of no sense, except messages containing only [emoticons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon) are acceptable.

But please note that `^\W*$` is not enough to check if the message contains really a useful text as a single letter, digit or underscore results already in a negative match and therefore message passed the validation check.